# A way to delete your posts even when they have upvoted answers or lots of activity?

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, legal, vote-to-delete

I was hoping there should be someway to delete some post even if it has lot of activity like say a couple of answers with upvotes. Here are my reasons -

1. Sometimes unfortunately my bad, but the question isn't right..I mean where we need to basically completely reword it..and edit would not be the answer, but I can't because it has too much activity.
2. Sometimes..I just want to delete the question because I found something similar and more important and worded better.
3. Instead of closing question why don't we just delete them? That would make it less clutter and easier to navigate.
4. Question posted sometimes in a hurry..gets lot of downvotes..and answers and realise it was silly but..then can't delete the question because too much activity..

Comment: Remember http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/ Once you bring to the community some content it is no longer yours alone.

Comment: Well yeah..but I think this will help the community in a way !

Comment: Flag for moderator attention. Deletion is too dangerous to make easy.

Comment: So If I flag for moderation...and say I want to delete it will work right..sorry never tried it..

Comment: If the moderator agrees that the reason you've given for wanting to delete your question is valid, he'll delete it for you. If he doesn't, then he won't. Be sure to give a good reason...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can flag your post for moderator attention. More times than not, your reasoning will be justified and **a moderator can remove the post for you.** But removing the ability to delete an *active* post is a way to prevent people from inappropriately or maliciously removing content licensed under Creative Commons.

The ability to delete your post is available when it has little activity (upvotes, answers, etc) because deleting it will typically have no effect on other parts of the system.

But once people start adding to your post, it becomes part of a collection. The other answers, the voting, and the comments all work together to create a cohesive collection. Arbitrarily deleting a portion of that collection could materially harm the value of that material… which has already been published under a Creative Common license for reuse.

Also, you *cannot* arbitrarily terminate your Creative Commons license grant.

http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/legalcode

That's what "perpetual" stated below means; continuing forever or indefinitely.

> 3. License Grant. Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, Licensor hereby grants You a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive, perpetual (for the duration of the applicable copyright) license to exercise the rights in the Work as stated below:

Even under Section (7) Termination, it explicitly says that, even if the author chooses to stop distributing the work, it does not serve to withdraw this license.

> Subject to the above terms and conditions, the license granted here is perpetual (for the duration of the applicable copyright in the Work). Notwithstanding the above, Licensor reserves the right to release the Work under different license terms or to stop distributing the Work at any time; provided, however that any such election will not serve to withdraw this License (or any other license that has been, or is required to be, granted under the terms of this License), and this License will continue in full force and effect unless terminated as stated above.

The usual "I am not a lawyer" disclaimers apply, but I have read that license agreement backwards and forwards and that's how I read it.

However, **you can request to remove from the Collection any credit as required by attribution (Section 4(c))**. We will do this on request, but the material is published as part of a collection and we feel that removal of that content would materially harm the collection licensed for reuse.

Comment: yeah..I understand now..thanks.

Comment: Is there any option for a moderator to make, say, Community own such post?

Comment: @Arjan Assuming you don't mean making it Community Wiki, there is nothing a diamond is capable of doing to dissociate a singular post from a user.

Comment: @Grace, no I did not mean CW (but I meant something like associate it to another "virtual" user). Too bad; it would be a pity to see posts go just because a user wants to be deleted.